# Problem in using conftest.py from a packaged pytest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am working on a pytest-framework that will be packed as a package. The setup file i am using for this is as this:

```
setup(
name='MyTestFrameWork',
version="2",
author='my name',
author_email='name@gmail.com',
description='My test framework',
long_description=open('README.md', 'rb').read().decode('utf-8'),
url='http://my.test.framework.dk',
license="Free loot",
packages=find_namespace_packages(),
python_requires=">=3.10",
include_package_data=True,
install_requires=['pytest'],

entry_points={"pytest11": ["MyTestFrameWork = MyTestFrameWork"]},
)
```

In this package (in the root of this folder MyTestFrameWork ) I have a conftest.py with some fixtures.

**MY problem/Question:**
When I import my framework from another python project eg: by importing the testframework. I cant get the framework to use the fixtures in the conftest ...... however,....

if i move the content from the conftest.py into `__init__.py` in my framework ie: in MyTestFrameWork folder the fixtures are working as expected.

why it is like this ....why cant i have my fixtures in the conftest.py instead of having them in the `__init__.py` am i missing something ?

for better view of my file-structure on the framework:

[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting, pls post the error trace? does your package only have fixtures? in another python project if you explicitly import the `from testframework import *` it should behave the same as `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ***conftest*** module in the `entry_points` definition. The [syntax](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#setuptools-entry-points) is following:

```py
entry_points={"pytest11": ["name_of_plugin = myproject.pluginmodule"]}
```

This means that for Pytest to load the fixtures from *conftest.py*, the setup should be following:

```py
setup(
    ...
    entry_points={"pytest11": ["MyTestFrameWork = MyTestFrameWork.conftest"]},
)
```

However, *conftest.py* is typically meant for auto-discovery within tests so in a plugin I'd actually **use a different name for the module containing the fixtures**.

Comment: great, thank you!
this helped ..yeah I will go for a different name.